# Spark Streaming process different DStreams in parallel and process jobs within one DStream linearly

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a application which needs to consume from Kafka queue maintain the batch order for each topic. I have created different DStreams for each topic. But when I run it each topic is consumed in a sequential manner. If I set "spark.streaming.concurrentJob=4" (n>1) then topics are consumed in parallel but inside same topic batches also processed parallely. (which I need to avoid) 
Is there a way to process different DStreams in parallel and process jobs within one DStream linearly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating multiple jobs, I would set the parallelism of the source operator to the number of topic partitions. For more information, please refer to this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#level-of-parallelism-in-data-receiving)

Comment: Each different datastream needs different data Formatting that is the reason why I need to consume each data stream separately.

Comment: Then you could create many input sources (of a single job) , each having different semantics, and union them.

Comment: You mean to create separate spark applications to each datastream.

Comment: No, you will have only one stream applicaiton. The application topology will consist of several source operators. Each source operator might have different sources and semantics. You will union those source operators and this will be your overall input stream.

Comment: It won't parallel process the different topics. can you clarify the your solution using pseudo code. since I don't think it address my concerns

Comment: Can you elaborate your solution